# How to write this in Rails 5 code, Lightbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lightbox2

Been trying to figure this out for two days now and ready to ask.
Here is the code I'm trying to convert to Rails 5 code:

```
<img src="/assets/small.jpg" alt="image">
<a href="/assets/bigger.jpg" data-lightbox="image1" 
data-title="Image Caption">
```

I've tried a bunch of different code, the closest is the following. The lightbox popup part works fine but the first image does not show.

```
 <%= link_to image_tag('gallery-1-small.jpg', alt: 'image'), image_path('gallery-1.jpg'), data: { lightbox: 'image-1', title: 'Image Caption'} %>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does "does not show" mean? Have you checked that the URL to the image is valid by trying to visit it in your browser?

Comment: In the plain HTML example the image is outside the link and in your Rails implementation it's inside, but I think that does not matter. What you tried *should* work. Did you follow trosborn's suggestion and checked that the URL of the first image is valid and that it can be displayed in a browser?

Comment: yes image is there. None of the suggestions worked. I finally could only get it to work by doing:

Comment: <%= image_tag('gallery-1.jpg', alt: 'image') %>
     <a href="/assets/gallery-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Image Caption">

Comment: But I was trying to write the whole thing as a rails helper but couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%= link_to "/assets/gallery-1.jpg", data: { lightbox: 'roadtrip', title: 'Image Caption'}  do %>
  <%= image_tag "/assets/gallery-1-small.jpg" %>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your **application.html.erb**.
Move this code `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` from the head to the end of body.

```html
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
   </body>
</html>
```